# WordPress apache and varnish: redirect loop for wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, apache, varnish

I've set up VPS with Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache.
I set up a single vhost and installed WordPress. 
All very straightforward with nothing unconventional.
The only settings in my .htaccess come from setting permalinks to be the names of the posts.

That configuration works with no issues.

Then I installed varnish from the repos.

I configured Apache to listen on port 8080. I set the vhost to respond to requests on port 8080. Varnish listens on port 80 before communicating with Apache on 8080.

After configuring that I restarted both Apache and Varnish.
And things work!

... almost!

The one single thing that doesn't work is this: requests for http://example.com/wp-admin return a redirect loop. Eventually the browser shows an error.

Every other route seems to succeed. Including routes to non-existent resources, which return WordPress's 404 page.

What does work are requests to http://example.com/wp-admin/index.php.

Other than configuring ports I haven't touched Varnish. I have no plugins for the WordPress site.

My default.vcl looks like this:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c204c826c3bf4b7c2e167a241fc3dad

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: are you using linux??

Comment: I think this is problem due to HHVM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929163/redirect-loop-when-using-varnish-nginx-https

Comment: Hi Vasim.
I did find that post a few hours ago. I'm not using HHVM. I did try a variation on that conditional for passing requests to wp-admin through. But my results didn't change.

Comment: It's usually best to tell Varnish to ignore requests to wp-admin, since it's the backend and doesn't make much sense to cache anyway.